# Do I need to make use of Offline Access in Google Sign-in to retrieve and save user info (name etc) on the backend?

Tags: android, google-signin, google-plus-signin

**Background:**

I am building an Android app which would required the user to sign-in/register to the service if they wish to contribute.

The service will need some basic info of the user (name, gender etc) on the backend in order to register them.

The app will be providing Google Sign-in as well.

**My understanding:**

Sending the Id-token to the backend could only give me the email of the user ([check](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/backend-auth#calling-the-tokeninfo-endpoint) the JSON the tokeninfo endpoint returns). In order to retreive additional user info on the backend irrespective of whether the user is signed-in or not I will need to get [Offline Access](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/offline-access) permission (more intimidating) from the user, get the access- and refresh-token, and then get the info.

Another option would be to retreive these info on the app and then send them to the backend along with the Id-token for verification and registration.

**Question(s):**

Can I pull additional info on the user while the user is still online (using the app) through the Id-token, on serverside/backend? Or should I request additional permission for offline access in order get them? Or, as mentioned in the previous section, pull the required info on app-side and send it over to the backend along with the Id-token?

Comment: Try the latest version of the Google Sign-In API on Android (Play Services 8.3+), you will get an ID token with more information for your backend: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2016/01/using-google-sign-in-with-your-server.html

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the information once then in my opinion it would be better to get the additional information in the app itself rather than asking for additional (with potential denial from user) permission to be used on server.

This will also make sure you have all the needed information while the user is being signed in.

Comment: Or I could verify/pull them everytime the users logs in? Is that standard/recommended procedure?

Comment: You pull the information in the app itself when user logs in. I am not sure about it being standard but seems more logical and straight forward in your case.